# Groupby ID in Pandas and get rows with latest date and value in another column greater than 0

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file where I need to find the ID with latest user activity that is not equal to 0.

input.csv:

```
 id  date             userActivity 
 1    2020-03-30            0
 2    2020-03-30            1
 3    2020-03-30            0
 1    2020-03-29            10
 2    2020-03-29            33
 3    2020-03-29            0
 1    2020-03-28            2
 2    2020-03-28            0
 3    2020-03-28            9
```

desired output.csv

```
 id     date             userActivity 
 1    2020-03-29            10
 2    2020-03-30            1
 3    2020-03-28            9
```

My code so far:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('path/to/my/input.csv')


activUsr = df.groupby('id').userActivity

df[df['id'].isin(activUsr[activUsr != 0].index)].to_csv('path/to/my/output.csv')
```

however, it throws the following error message:

```
Exception: Column(s) userActivity already selected
```

Could someone help me with this? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove `0` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filter rows with no `0` by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for not equal, then sorting by both columns with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last remove duplicated by `id` column with keep last rows by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df1 = (df[df['userActivity'].ne(0)]
         .sort_values(['id','date'])
         .drop_duplicates('id', keep='last'))
print (df1)
   id       date  userActivity
3   1 2020-03-29            10
1   2 2020-03-30             1
8   3 2020-03-28             9
```